# Redirect to specific url based on user input but if no pre-defined keyword exists search the site

Tags: javascript, search

ok so, second question here, let me start by saying I know NOTHING about javascript yet, everything I use is just cut and paste from here and there, so go easy on me :-p.

I have a customer who wants to set up a search box and if someone types in a certain pre defined keyword it goes to a specific page.  I grabbed this code off of here to accomplish that part:

```
 <form id='formName' name='formName' onsubmit='redirect();return false;'>
            <input type='text' id='userInput' name='userInput' value=''>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
        </form>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function redirect() {
           var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toLowerCase();
            switch(input) {
                case 'keyword1':
                    window.location.replace('page1.html');
                    break;
                case 'keyword2':
                    window.location.replace('page2.html');
                    break;
                default:
                    window.location.replace('error.html');
                    break;
            }


        }
        </script>
```

Now I am also using the sphider php search script, which I have using this embedded form:

```
<form action="search/search.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="query" id="query"  value="SEARCH" columns="2" 
autocomplete="off" delay="1500"  
onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''"   
onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" >
<input type="submit" value="" id="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="1">
</form>
```

Is there any way I can combine the two so that if they search for the predefined keyword they get directed to the correct page but then if their search doesn't contain a predefined keyword it searches with sphider?

Sorry if this question is ludicrous, like I said, I'm new :-p

Thanks

Comment: Haven't tried anything, Javascript is Greek to me, I just started learning today, up til now I've just copied and pasted.  Usually I just do plain html/css sites for small mom and pop businesses.  but this customer wants the search to function this way.

Comment: the best way of learning is trying ;)

Comment: I'm not quite clear about why the _sphider_ form is doing what it's doing on the `onfocus` and `onblur` events. Other than that, you should be able to put the `onsubmit` code from your predefined search in here.

Comment: that I actually did try, it didn't work.  the onfocus and onblur events make the word SEARCH appear as default in the search box and make it disappear when the user clicks in the box. Again, just something I copied from somewhere else

Comment: @Jared I've posted an answer. Tell me what happens when you try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** : Ok so the problem was just that you had to do a `return redirect();` to ensure the false returns correctly. I made a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/3UbLa/1/

---

I'm don't know anything about sphider search but from what you posted you should be able to combine the two like below:

Your JS will change like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        function redirect() {
           //look for text inside the NEW textbox
           var input = document.getElementById('query').value.toLowerCase();
            switch(input) {
                case 'keyword1':
                   //put this to see if this code runs 
                   //alert("Test");// UNCOMMENT THIS
                    window.location.replace('page1.html');
                    break;
                case 'keyword2':
                    window.location.replace('page2.html');
                    break;
                default://no keyword detected so we submit the form.
                    return true;
                    break;
            }
            return false;//don't let the form submit
        }
</script>
```

Your html will change to :

```
<form action="search/search.php" method="get" 
                              onsubmit='return redirect();'>
<!-- pretty much the same thing except you remove the return false  !-->
<input type="text" name="query" id="query"  value="SEARCH" columns="2" 
autocomplete="off" delay="1500"  
onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" 
onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" >
<input type="submit" value="" id="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: This just searches the site for 'keyword1' , I thought maybe it was because I forgot to change the 'getElementById' to 'query' but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Whoops. I fixed that. Are you saying that it doesn't goto `page1.html` when you type `keyword1` ?

Comment: nope, it just does a normal search for the phrase 'keyword1' as if the extra script wasnt there at all

Comment: @Jared I've updated my post. See if putting an alert works for you? Also if you have chrome, you can press `F12(Windows) -> Sources -> Expand the pane on the left -> Open your html page` and put a breakpoint inside the redirect function and see if it hits in there.

Comment: awesome, thanks so much.  I'm learning a bunch just from this.